# Non stop console logs, I am having issues with setInterval and for loops

Tags: javascript, for-loop, setinterval

So, I have this computer function...  console.log(counter); AND console.log(que.length); just print on the console non stop(well over 100K times so far)... why is that? what am I doing wrong here?...

Basically this code is supposed to make the computer play and animation turnEvent function each 250 milli seconds. And this setInterval "looping" should stop when counter = length of array que.

initially counter is = 0; tried changing it to 2. Had zero effect.
This is the for loop calling the computer function just in case you need that:

```
        for (var i = rects.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
            console.log("for loop - adding box to que.");
            if (collides([rects[i]], g.x, g.y)) {
                console.log("X og Y hnit computer:");
                console.log("X-hnit: " + g.x);
                console.log("Y-hnit: " + g.y);
                que.push([rects[i]]);
                console.log(que.length);
                computer();
            }
        };
```

Down below is the computer function which has the console log problem.

```
       function computer(){
            var counter = 2;
            var i = setInterval(function(){
            // do your thing
                if (containsObject(que, rects)) {
                    turnEvent([que[counter-2]].x, [que[counter-2]].y)
                    counter++
                };
                console.log(counter);
                console.log(que.length);
                if(counter == que.length) {
                    userTurn++;
                    computerTurn++;
                    userRight = false; //resets for next round.
                    clearInterval(i);
                    user();//it's the users turn.
                }
            }, 250);
        }
```

Comment: My guess is `containsObject(que, rects)` is always false, thus preventing `counter` from incrementing resulting in an infinite loop.

Comment: How often are you calling `computer`?

Comment: @Kevin B, no this happened even before i started using the containObject function.

Comment: @Bergi just in that for loop above.

Comment: Oops, I'm blind. So this loop runs only once with a finite number of `rects`? Good. Where is `que` initialised, and in what other code than the shown is it used? Also, you seem to have a fair amount of debugging log statement in the code - so what do they log? What values of `counter` and `que.length` do you repeatedly get?

Comment: @Bergi in this case i get counter = 2, que.length = 1. I don't really use que anywhere else. On top of my file i declare que = Array();

Comment: So that means there is one `rects` array in the `que`, your counter is wrongly initialised as `2` (which never makes it equal to `1`), and your counter for some reason does never increase to `3` as expected (probably because of the reason Kevin mentioned).